# Node.js Twilio sequential calling - handling call back status

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

So I can make twilio calls to individual number and also pass parameters to it.

I am having issues with, making sequential calls. I.E if user1 doesn't pick up, reaches voice mail, hangs up or presses 0 it should call user2 and so on till someone presses the key 1.

I am able to use gather to get response for 1 and 0.

If the user picks up and presses one - it should record as accept. If they don’t pick up, press 0 or Hangup - it should call a different number with its own parameters.

It goes through the whole list till someone accepts (presses one)

I have started looking into statuscallbackevent but not sure how to proceed with it. The numbers are being stored in redis with parameters that need to be "said"

I was wondering how should one approach this?

Thank you

Here is the code block I use

```
require('dotenv').config();
var accountSid = process.env.accountSid; 
var authToken = process.env.authToken;   
var accountPhone=process.env.accountPhone;


const Twilio = require('twilio');
const client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);




//hmget
var sendCallNotification=(payload,phoneArray)=>{


var phone1=phoneArray[0];
phoneArray.splice(0,1);
client.api.calls
  .create({
    url: 'url/voice?email'+payload.email,
    to: phone1,
    from: process.env.accountPhone,
    statusCallback: 'url?email='+payload.email,
    statusCallbackEvent: ["completed","busy"]
  })
  .then(call => console.log("making call"+ call.sid))
  .catch((error)=>{console.log("error making call"+ error)});
}



module.exports.sendCallNotification=sendCallNotification;
```

In my url post response

```
app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
const twiml = new VoiceResponse();


  /** helper function to set up a <Gather> */
  function gather() {
    const gatherNode = twiml.gather({ numDigits: 1 });
    gatherNode.say('Hell there, service '+request.query.email
        +' minutes. To accept, press 1. To decline press 0 or hang up.');

    // If the user doesn't enter input, loop
    twiml.redirect('/voice');
  }

  // If the user entered digits, process their request
  if (request.body.Digits) {
    switch (request.body.Digits) {
      case '1':
        twiml.say('We will let the client know. Thank you.');
       // Insert into database how do I stop calls from proceeding here
        break;
       case '0':
        twiml.say('Thank you. Good bye');
       //calls should proceed to the next one
        break;  
      default:
       //calls should move to the next one after 10 seconds
        break;
    }
  } else {
    // If no input was sent, use the <Gather> verb to collect user input
    gather();
  }

  // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});



app.post('/statusCallBack', (request, response) => {
  console.log(request);


  // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send();
});
```

I guess I am still lost - not sure how do I make my calls move to the next one or stop the calls.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck and can you share the part of the code that is not working for you?

Comment: @philnash sorry I was away for a while. Ill post the code in a couple of hours here. I think I have most of it figured out. But would still love to have another set of eyes go over it

Comment: No worries, let me know when I can help :)

Comment: Hey @philnash, I have added my code above. I still have some issues regarding how to make my calls stop after accept or proceed to other calls. What do you think? 

By the way I just show an array here - but I am pulling from  redis key storage. So if someone accepts I can completely empty that key storage value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, to stop the call once you are satisfied with the result, you can return the [`<Hangup/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup) element.

```
  if (request.body.Digits) {
    switch (request.body.Digits) {
      case '1':
        twiml.say('We will let the client know. Thank you.');
        twiml.hangup
        // Insert into database
        break;
```

Second, if you receive a `'0'` from the `Digits` parameter, then you should also hangup, but then [use the REST API to make a new call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). You'll need to keep a list of the phone numbers that you have called so far or a pointer to the next number to call, then dial that one and move the pointer or add it to the list.

```
   case '0':
    twiml.say('Thank you. Good bye');
    twiml.hangup
    client.calls.create( // call parameters for next call to next number )
    break;
```

You need to use the status callback URL for the case when the user hangs up. You'll want to register for the "completed" events. "busy" is not an option here, a "busy" call will be a completed call, but the [`CallStatus` parameter to your callback URL will tell you whether the call was "completed", "no-answer", "busy" or "failed"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/voice-overview#callstatus-values).

If you get a callback to your URL where the `CallStatus` is "busy", "no-answer" or "failed" then you should use the REST API to create the next call again.

If you get a callback to your URL where the `CallStatus` is "completed" you will need to work out whether it was just hung up or completed correctly. Since you are saving something to a database when the user enters `"1"` you can check against your database to see if that something is there. If it's not, then the call was hung up and you'll need to generate a new call with the REST API again.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Sorry philnash, just got to work on it that works perfect. I have a question regarding voice mail - how do you capture voice mail - aka if you get voice mail move on?

The other thing I have noticed is if a user hangsup in the middle of the call it just says completed -- so I can't capture that and make a second call. Anyway to avoid that?

-- Ah never mind just understood your hangup part. Maybe I can use the same for voicemail

Comment: You might find that [answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection) can help you with voicemail.

Comment: Sorry to necro this @philnash but does Twilio have a recommended method of storing the previously dialed numbers in order to iterate to the next? My logic is to go the route of an array and then shift() it to remove the first element so it only contains numbers yet to be dialed?

Comment: @Talisman This interaction is powered by webhooks, each time a new call connects or is hung up on or responds to the `<Gather>` will result in a new HTTP request to your application. For that reason, I wouldn't try to store the numbers in an array in memory. Instead you will want to persist your list of numbers somewhere and keep moving down the list as you need to.